# How to make swipeable TextField in QML?

Tags: ios, qml, textfield, swipe, qtquickcontrols2

Here's what I've got: a SwipeDelegate in a ListView and TextField that fills this delegate. When I'm trying to swipe delegate, TextField gets focus, and I'm not able to do it. 
Here's what I need: to swipe TextField when I'm trying to swipe it and to pass focus only when I'm tapping on it. An example of what I need is behaviour of notes in "Reminders" application on iOS. Is it possible to change behaviour of this construction somehow to make it react on swipe like I need? 
Simplified code:

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Controls 2.3
import QtQuick.Window 2.3

Window {
    id: root
    width: 320
    height: 480
    visible: true

    ListModel {
        id: simpleModel

        ListElement {
            text: "some text"
        }

        ListElement {
            text: "another text"
        }
    }

    ListView {
        id: simpleView
        model: simpleModel
        anchors.fill: parent

        delegate: SwipeDelegate {
            width: parent.width
            contentItem: TextField {
                text: model.text
                onAccepted: model.text = text
            }
            swipe.right: Label {
                id: deleteLabel
                text: "Delete"
                color: "white"
                verticalAlignment: Label.AlignVCenter
                padding: 12
                height: parent.height
                anchors.right: parent.right

                SwipeDelegate.onClicked: simpleView.model.remove(index);

                background: Rectangle {
                    color: "tomato"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you make your example complete so that we can run it? Add the missing imports, move swipe.right to the correct place, add some dummy text where necessary so that stuff shows up, etc.

Comment: Updated code sample in question. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I was going to suggest was:

```
readOnly: true
```

and then react to clicks on the `SwipeDelegate` itself to enable the editor:

```
onClicked: {
    if (!swipe.complete) {
        contentItem.visible = true
        contentItem.forceActiveFocus()
    }
}
```

This doesn't work though, because it seems that `TextField` consumes mouse events even when it's read-only. I'm not sure if this is a bug or not; it could make sense that it blocks mouse events from going through to items beneath it.

Anyway, you can hide the `TextField` to prevent it interfering with mouse events, and show some text in its place:

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Controls 2.3
import QtQuick.Window 2.3

Window {
    id: root
    width: 320
    height: 480
    visible: true

    ListModel {
        id: simpleModel

        ListElement {
            text: "some text"
        }

        ListElement {
            text: "another text"
        }
    }

    ListView {
        id: simpleView
        model: simpleModel
        anchors.fill: parent

        delegate: SwipeDelegate {
            id: swipeDelegate
            width: parent.width
            text: model.text

            onClicked: {
                if (!swipe.complete) {
                    contentItem.visible = true
                    contentItem.forceActiveFocus()
                }
            }

            Text {
                anchors.fill: contentItem
                anchors.leftMargin: contentItem.leftPadding
                verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
                text: model.text
                visible: !contentItem.visible
            }

            contentItem: TextField {
                text: model.text
                visible: false
                onAccepted: model.text = text
            }
            swipe.right: Label {
                id: deleteLabel
                text: "Delete"
                color: "white"
                verticalAlignment: Label.AlignVCenter
                padding: 12
                height: parent.height
                anchors.right: parent.right

                SwipeDelegate.onClicked: simpleView.model.remove(index);

                background: Rectangle {
                    color: "tomato"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I don't know what iOS does for accepting/cancelling the input, but I'm sure you can figure that part out. Respond to that event and hide the `TextField` and it should all just work.

Comment: Oh, thank you very much! This is exactly what I looked for.